# Why bother with dotnet build before dotnet publish?

Tags: build, .net-core

Welp.  This seems like the type of question where I'll facepalm seeing the answer.

So...

Why bother with `dotnet build` before doing a `dotnet publish`?

`build` automatically does a `restore`.  Cool.

It seems `publish` does a `build` (unless you tell it not to).  So... Why bother doing the build if you're going to publish right after?  Why not just publish and everything happens in one step?

For further clarity...

I am asking in a basic scenario like:

- `dotnet build -c Release MyProj`
- `dotnet publish -c Release -o /somedir MyProj`

versus just

- `dotnet publish -c Release -o /somedir MyProj`

They seem to do the same thing.

Comment: I'm not going to directly respond to your question, I'll leave that to someone who knows the difference, if there is one. However, if you have 1 command that does 17 things, and you have 17 other commands that does 1 thing, doing these 17 commands, one at a time, gives you a much better chance of handling problems as there is just a handful of problems with each of those 17 commands that you need to handle, whereas that 1 command that does 17 things have the potential of 17*handful problems.

Comment: (opinion) However, knowing that this was built by Microsoft, there is probably going to be some major differences, like there is with nuget packages. With nuget packages you have `nuget install`, `nuget restore`, `dotnet restore` and `msbuild /t:restore;xxx` which all seemingly does different things and you probably need a few of them just to get the build going. So who can tell. If  `dotnet publish` does what you want, I'd say ignore whatever the documentation tells you, go with it.

Comment: Please note: if you do a dotnet publish --no-restore, then publish doesn't build and you therefore needs the build step.

Comment: @mslot Is there any documentation about `--no-restore` disabling the build step too during `dotnet publish`?

Comment: @abhim i haven't read that anywhere

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You are right that `dotnet publish` automatically does everything `dotnet build` already does. In most cases - as in your scenario mentioned in the question - that means an additional `dotnet build` is not necessary.

Do note that you can `dotnet build` a solution, but should only `dotnet publish` individual project files. Publishing solutions likely leads to unexpected results (from overriding files of different versions to publishing library projects in configurations that should not be published to the same output directory as referencing applications etc.)

Over time there was a community ask to allow both publishing and testing without potentially rebuilding the app, because some users felt more comfortable only ever publishing an application with the same binaries that have been tested so their build scripts can look like:

1. `dotnet build the.sln -c Release`
2. `dotnet test -c Release --no-build`
3. `dotnet publish the\app.csproj --no-build -c Release`

Comment: Is there a way to use ```MSBuild /t:Publish --no-build``` or equivalent at the MSBuild level? I don't see a ```--no-build``` argument in the MSBuild command line documentation. I call MSbuild directly on my csproj files and would like to separate the publish and build operations.