# Publish NET 6 app in pipeline fails with "type not found" exception

Tags: azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I try to publish my net 6 app but that part of the pipeline fails on the publishing step. At first, why do all examples have a build step BEFORE publish, if publish actually calls msbuild ?

Based on an example I found I call dotnet build via script and this PASSES. The MS docs state that all parameters in publish are passed to msbuild. As of below I use the EXACT same properties but publish build fails with some "type not found" exceptions (error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ValueTask<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

How can I fix this ?

WORKS

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --framework $(dotNetFramework) -t:restore /m:1 /nr:false
  displayName: 'Build .NET 6 Application'

FAILS;

- script: dotnet publish --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --framework $(dotNetFramework) -t:restore /m:1 /nr:false --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'publish .NET 6 Application'

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, you can add a restore task before the dotnet publish script and check if it could work.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- script: |
   dotnet publish  ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration)  -t:restore /m:1 /nr:false --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
   

  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

I suggest that you can directly use the existing dotnet task to replace the script task.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

> why do all examples have a build step BEFORE publish, if publish actually calls msbuild ?

Regarding with this question, you can refer to this ticket: [Why bother with dotnet build before dotnet publish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837524/why-bother-with-dotnet-build-before-dotnet-publish)

Answer (score 0):

Your build server maybe using an older version of dotnet sdk. Add "**Use .Net Core**" task before you start building with "**.Net Core**" task.

[image: Use .Net Core Task]

Make sure you set, "**Version**" to "**6.0.x**" and check "**Include Preview Versions**"

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'dotnet use'
  inputs:
    version: 6.0.x
    includePreviewVersions: true
```