# Building .net Framework and .net Core applications in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: .net, jenkins, .net-core

I am creating templates for building a .net Framework and .net Core applications using a Jenkins pipeline and have a few questions (unfortunately I'm not that familiar with .net):

- Should I use dotnet commands for Framework or msbuild commands?  According to [this](https://www.codememo.dev/2020/04/build-net-framework-and-net-core-projects-with-jenkins/) article, msbuild should be used for Framework, as dotnet isn't fully compatible; is that still the case?
- For Framework builds, it sounds as if there doesn't need to be both a build and publish command, just a publish (which, by default, will do a build); see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837524/why-bother-with-dotnet-build-before-dotnet-publish) . Is that correct?
- The same answer also mentions that a publish should always be done against project files and not a solution file.  For applications that have multiple project files, it is my understanding that there will be a "main" project file that will reference the other project files, so doing a publish against that csproj file should be sufficient, correct?
- Could someone explain when (if ever) a publish profile is needed for building/publishing and deploying through a CI/CD Pipeline?

Thanks

Comment: .NET Framework and .NET Core (which includes .NET 6 and later, "Core" was dropped for marketing reasons) are completely different SDKs and runtimes. You can't use or build .NET Framework at all on Linux machines. Unless Jenkins runs on Windows, you can only build .NET Core applications

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - we have Windows and Linux build agents for Jenkins.  We point the Jenkinsfile to use the Windows build agents for Framework apps and Linux build agents for Core applications.