# optimizing docker dotnet build

Tags: .net, docker, rider

One of the dockerfiles I have is this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/AnalyzerHistory/AnalyzerHistory.fsproj", "Services/AnalyzerHistory/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/AnalyzerHistory/AnalyzerHistory.fsproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/AnalyzerHistory"
RUN dotnet build "AnalyzerHistory.fsproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AnalyzerHistory.fsproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AnalyzerHistory.dll"]
```

the build stages of interest are these:

```
#13 [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "AnalyzerHistory.fsproj" -c Release -o /app/build
#13 0.425 MSBuild version 17.7.3+4fca21998 for .NET
#13 1.423   Determining projects to restore...
#13 3.952   Restored /src/Credentials/Credentials.fsproj (in 551 ms).
...
#13 49.47   AnalyzerHistory -> /app/build/AnalyzerHistory.dll
#13 49.51
#13 49.52 Build succeeded.
#13 49.52     0 Warning(s)
#13 49.52     0 Error(s)
#13 49.52
#13 49.52 Time Elapsed 00:00:48.84
#13 DONE 49.8s

#14 [publish 1/1] RUN dotnet publish "AnalyzerHistory.fsproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
#14 0.667 MSBuild version 17.7.3+4fca21998 for .NET
#14 1.519   Determining projects to restore...
#14 3.503   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
#14 8.960   Credentials -> /src/Credentials/bin/Release/net7.0/Credentials.dll
...
#14 41.72   AnalyzerHistory -> /src/Services/AnalyzerHistory/bin/Release/net7.0/AnalyzerHistory.dll
#14 41.80   AnalyzerHistory -> /app/publish/
#14 DONE 42.0s
```

I don't understand why, after the build stage, the publish stage is re-compiling everything. It seems like it doubles the build time.

Should I just go for publish and skip the build stage? This docker file is from a template generated by Rider.

Comment: Visual Studio creates Dockerfiles with the same structure. I don't understand why and they don't explain it. I don't see any harm in going straight for publish and leaving out the build step if you don't need it.

Comment: I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332539/why-do-we-build-and-publish-as-two-steps-when-publish-also-builds

Comment: One thing that I notice is that build and publish are in different stages. That allows you to do `docker build --target=build` and have the build stop after build but before publish. I don't know what the purpose of that would be though. But if you just wanted to do build and publish, why not do them in the same stage? I don't understand it :)

Comment: I think having `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` in different stages is just a consequence of the different nature of both tools: as the name implies, `dotnet build` is meant to _build_ a project, whereas `dotnet publish` focuses on _publishing_ a project, i. e. omitting irrelevant things (you'll notice fewer files after `dotnet publish -o /publish` than `dotnet build -c Release -o /build`)